# C++ Builder XE 2 -- How to display variable data in a TEdit control?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I hope you can help me here Guys. What I´ve been doing in the past 3 weeks is to try to display the content of 3 variables ( 1  char variable which contains a '-' or a '+' sign accordingly and two other integer variables which contain temperature measurements ) What I´m trying to do id to display the content of those variables in a TEdit control something like : + 26.3 . Simple as that.

I have tried several functionalities with no sucess, let me show you:

(Where temp_txtBox_Cond is the name of the TEdit control)

```
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text=(L"%c %i. %i",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec,test_buf,n);

temp_txtBox_Cond->Text.printf(L"%c %i. %i",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);

sprintf(test_buf,"%c %i.%i",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);
temp_txtBox_Cond ->Text.sprintf(L"%c %i.%i",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec,test_buf);

temp_txtBox_Cond->Text=("%c %i. %i",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);

temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = AnsiString(temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);

temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = (AnsiString(temp_sign)+AnsiString(temp_temp_int)+AnsiString    (temp_temp_dec));

String s(temp_sign);
String d(temp_temp_dec);
String i(temp_temp_int);

temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = s+" "+i+"."+d;
```

With NO Sucess. This is VERY Frustrating.

PLEASE Guys Need your help. Thanks in advanced.

---

Well it´s kind of weird because with most of the above functionalities What I get is a `0`, `+0.0` or `hq3Pˆ15PPhå` ( this one sounds like memory issue ). Let me show you :

With :

```
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = (L"%c %i.%i",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec,test_buf);
```

I get : `hq3Pˆ15PPhå`

With :

```
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text.printf(L"%c %i. %i",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);
```

I get Nada the text box is blank

With :

```
sprintf(test_buf,"%d. %d",temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text =(test_buf,"%c %d. %d",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);`
```

I get 0.

With :

```
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text =("%c %d. %d",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);`
```

I get 0 as well.

and With:

```
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = AnsiString(temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec): I got +0.0
```

Those are the errors.

Hi Remy,

Sure no problem. This is the code that I use to get the temp_sig, temp_temp_int and temp_temp_dec :

```
 WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{    
ikor_msg_id = ikor_id_bld (app_priority, zone, dest_UCP, 0x20, 0x03);
wait_for_msg(h, 0x5200, 500, data);
if (data[0] == 1)
{
temp_sign = '+';
}
else if (data[0] == 0)
{
temp_sign = '-';
}
else
{
temp_sign = '?';
}

temp_temp_int = data[1];
temp_temp_int <<= 8;
temp_temp_int += data[2];
temp_temp_dec = temp_temp_int;
temp_temp_int /= 10;
temp_temp_dec -= (temp_temp_int * 10);
}
```

and here where I´m trying to display the data:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::temp_txtBox_CondChange(TObject *Sender )
{
unsigned long ikor_msg_id = 0;
long ikor_id_bld( long p_temp, long z_temp, long d_temp, int m_temp, int s_temp);
int wait_for_msg(CANHANDLE handle,int id,int timeout,unsigned char *data);
CANHANDLE h;
unsigned char data [8];

/***Here is where i tried all the attempts that I posted ****/

}
```

And the variables I declared them in a header:

```
#ifndef __Variables_Cond__
#define __Variables_Cond__

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif



unsigned int temp_temp_int;
unsigned int temp_temp_dec;
unsigned char temp_sign;


#ifdef __cplusplus
```

}
    #endif

```
#endif
```

Comment: With all attempts you tried, what are their error messages?

Comment: Hi Joachim. Good question forgot to post that :

Comment: Also tried to debug line per line and when come to the point of checking the content of the variables I clearly see the temperature and the sign. i.e : temp_sign -> contains '+', temp_temp_int -> contains (26 , which is what I expect to contain) and temp_temp_dec -> (23 which is the decimal part and ofcourse correct as expected). What I donot get is to display the data.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following:

```
    TCHAR temp_buf[256];
    wsprintf(temp_buf, _T("%c %d.%d"), temp_sign, temp_temp_int, temp_temp_dec);

    temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = temp_buf;
```

Comment: Thanks Artem. But with your suggestion I got : +0.0

Comment: @user1479770 So we're close to the solution, it's good. Could you please show me what types of the variables temp_sign, temp_temp_int, temp_temp_dec?

Comment: Yes please. In fact I´m using those variables in a header in order to keep them global. This is how I have declared them : unsigned int temp_temp_int=0;unsigned int temp_temp_dec=0; and unsigned char temp_sign='+'; And thanks again.

Comment: @user1479770 If values are '+', 0 and 0, you should got "+ 0.0", it's expected.

Comment: Run your code through the debugger.  Make sure that the variables are not + 0 0.

Comment: ok. I just debbuged the code and I can see that the values of the temperture is loaded in the variables . I´m getting in temp_sign =  + , temp_temp_int=26 and in temp_temp_dec = .26 which is correct. But the issue persists I can get those values in the textbox In this moment I´m only getting 0. Yep that´s it 0. Any suggestions ? Thanks guys.

Comment: Also removed the 0´s and the '+' from the variables.

Comment: Assuming the code has been fixed of bugs, there is no way the variables can contain values other than `+` `0` `0` but yet appear as `+` `0` `0` in the formatted string. Something else is still wrong in your code. Please show the latest code you are actually using, including the variable declarations and assignments.

Comment: I prefer deleaker or valgrind for similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the wrong results because your attempts are wrong for what you are attempting, and most of them stem from the same root problem - you are misusing the `,` operator.  In an expression rather than a perameter list, the `,` operator performs the operations on both sides, and the result of the operator is the result of the right-hand operation.  You are chaining multiple `,` operations together in your expressions and expecting them to result in something they really do not.

> temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = (L"%c %i.%i",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec,test_buf);

This is effectively the same as the following:

```
L"%c %i.%i"; // no-op
temp_sign; // no-op
temp_temp_int; // no-op
temp_temp_dec; // no-op
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = test_buf;
```

You get `hq3Pˆ15PPhå` because the contents of `test_buf` have not been initialized beforehand.

> temp_txtBox_Cond->Text.printf(L"%c %i. %i",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);

This is effectively the same as the following:

```
String temp = temp_txtBox_Cond->Text;
L"%c %i. %i"; // no-op
temp_sign; // no-op
temp_temp_int; // no-op
temp_temp_dec; // no-op
temp.printf(temp_temp_dec);
```

You get a blank result because you are not assigning anything to the `Text` property at all.  You are reading the `Text` property and then calling `printf()` on the temp `String` that it returns, but then you are not assigning that `String` back to the `Text` property afterwards.

> sprintf(test_buf,"%d. %d",temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);
>   temp_txtBox_Cond->Text =(test_buf,"%c %d. %d",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);

This is effectively the same as the following:

```
sprintf(test_buf, "%d. %d", temp_temp_int, temp_temp_dec);     
test_buf; // no-op
"%c %d. %d"; // no-op
temp_sign; // no-op
temp_temp_int; // no-op
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = temp_temp_dec;
```

You get `"0"` in the `Text` because `temp_temp_dec` is 0 to begin with (despite what you think you see in the debugger).

> temp_txtBox_Cond->Text =("%c %d. %d",temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec);`

This is effectively the same as the following:

```
"%c %d. %d"; // no-op
temp_sign; // no-op
temp_temp_int; // no-op
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = temp_temp_dec;
```

Same result as above.

> temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = AnsiString(temp_sign,temp_temp_int,temp_temp_dec)

This is effectively the same as the following:

```
temp_sign; // no-op
temp_temp_int; // no-op
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = AnsiString(temp_temp_dec);
```

Which will result in `"0"` again.  There is no way you can get `"+0.0"` in the `Text` with that code.

With all of that said, use one of these instead:

```
Char temp_sign = L'+'; // note: upper 'C'har = "%c"
int temp_temp_int = 26;
int temp_temp_dec = 3;
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = String().sprintf(L"%c %i.%i", temp_sign, temp_temp_int, temp_temp_dec);
```

.

```
char temp_sign = '+'; // note: lower 'c'har = "%hc"
int temp_temp_int = 26;
int temp_temp_dec = 3;
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = String().sprintf(L"%hc %i.%i", temp_sign, temp_temp_int, temp_temp_dec);
```

.

```
Char temp_sign = L'+'; // or lower-case 'c'har, doesn't matter
int temp_temp_int = 26;
int temp_temp_dec = 3;
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = Format(L"%s %i.%i", ARRAY_OF_CONST(( temp_sign, temp_temp_int, temp_temp_dec )) );
```

.

```
Char temp_sign = L'+'; // note: upper 'C'har = "%C"
int temp_temp_int = 26;
int temp_temp_dec = 3;
char test_buf[24];
sprintf(test_buf, "%C %i.%i", temp_sign, temp_temp_int, temp_temp_dec); 
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = test_buf;
```

.

```
char temp_sign = '+'; // note: lower 'c'har = "%c"
int temp_temp_int = 26;
int temp_temp_dec = 3;
char test_buf[24];
sprintf(test_buf, "%c %i.%i", temp_sign, temp_temp_int, temp_temp_dec); 
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = test_buf;
```

.

```
Char temp_sign = L'+'; // or lower 'c'char, doesn't matter
int temp_temp_int = 26;
int temp_temp_dec = 3;
temp_txtBox_Cond->Text = String(temp_sign) + L" " + String(temp_temp_int) + L"." + String(temp_temp_dec);
```